# javascript / ajax works in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I put the whole code in just to be safe, but I really just want to fix the ajax part of the code at the bottom where it updates parts of my site every second. It's important that it works in both firefox and chrome, and I just recently realized it doesn't work in FF. Could anyone just give me a tip as to why it doesn't work in FF? I'm assuming it's a very small error.

```js
var ls=0;
var roulet=0;
var clos=0;
var timerinterval;
var timerinterval2;

window.onload = function() {
 timerinterval = setInterval("reloadinfo()",1000);
        timerinterval2 = setInterval("lastwinner()", 10000);
 $(document).on('click', '.sound-link-on', function() {
                $('.sound-link-on').addClass('hidden');
                $('.sound-link-off').removeClass('hidden');
                var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/1.mp3');
    var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement2.setAttribute('src', 'audio/1.mp3');
    var audioElement3 = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement3.setAttribute('src', 'audio/1.mp3');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.sound-link-off', function() {
                $('.sound-link-off').addClass('hidden');
                $('.sound-link-on').removeClass('hidden');
                var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/audio.mp3');
    var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement2.setAttribute('src', 'audio/msg.mp3');
    var audioElement3 = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement3.setAttribute('src', 'audio/open.wav');
        });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.closech', function() {
    $('.closech').addClass('hidden');
    $('.closechs').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.hjgf').removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.closechs', function() {
    $('.closech').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.closechs').addClass('hidden');
    $('.hjgf').addClass('hidden');
        });
  
};



function alert2(txt,typet) {
 var n = noty({
  layout: 'bottomRight',
  text: txt,
  type: typet,
  timeout: 10000
 });
 audioElement.play();
}

function lastwinner() {
if(roulet == 0) {
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "lastwinner.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $('#lastwinner').html(msg);
  }
 });
}
}

function reloadinfo() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "currentchance.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $("#mychance").text(msg);
  }
 });
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "currentitem.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $("#myitem").text(msg);
  }
 });
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "currentbank.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $('#money_round').text(msg+'');
  }
 });
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "items.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $('.rounditems').html(msg);
  }
 });
 $.ajax({ 
  type: "GET",
  url: "currentitems.php", 
  success: function(msg){ 
   $(".selector-items-counter").html(msg); 
  } 
 }); 
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "currentitemswidth.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $('#meter').width(msg);
  }
 });
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "timeleft.php",
  success: function(msg){
   $('#timeleft').html(msg);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Please provide us with the output you see on the console, or the full page so that we can run your code.

Comment: In the firefox developer console? Nothing. The live page is at http://csgomid.com